# Saving JSON to file, changing output if exists

Tags: php, arrays, json, save

I am saving array data to a .json file with PHP. The .json file is then called in elsewhere by some JS and put into a variable.

Here's the code for the PHP:

```
$fetch = mysqli_query($connection, "SELECT * FROM mrb_prprty WHERE `nationalid` = '". $nationalid ."' AND `author` = '" .$username. "'");
$return_arr = array();

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($fetch)) {
    $row_array['firstName'] = $row['fname'];
    $row_array['lastName'] = $row['lname'];
    $row_array['nationality'] = $row['nationality'];
    $row_array['phone'] = $row['mobile'];
    $row_array['email'] = $row['email'];
    $row_array['street'] = $row['street'];
    $row_array['towncity']  = $row['towncity'];
    $row_array['postcode']= $row['postcode'];
    $row_array['county'] = $row['county'];
    $row_array['country'] = $row['country'];
    $row_array['rentpw'] = $row['rentpw'];
    $row_array['nationalid'] = $row['nationalid'];
    $row_array['passport'] = $row['passport'];
    $row_array['isFavorite'] = $row['favourite'];

    array_push($return_arr,$row_array);
}

$json_mrb = json_encode($return_arr);

$myFile = "userdata/". $username .".json";

$method = (file_exists($myFile)) ? 'a' : 'w';
$fh = fopen($myFile,$method);
fwrite($fh, $json_mrb."\n");
```

When this is executed for the first time, it will detect if the file exists & either create a new file or append to the existing one depending on the result.

Here's a preview of the '.json' file after running the PHP code above for the first time:

```
[{"firstName":"Ryan","lastName":"Butterworth","nationality":"rKqF01JNdAB1\/EjPW1sulcHzA+Lqp3y\/aaNtpixFphA=","phone":"6jAbOoIal2Eh73neklZgXcA2jJ3831uRiJWE74fADD8=","email":"gpLkiFg4ju4jv4QK6nftnPCqmzdENbsDt4ayI4L1rrkXvg0VJkxmP9Ac57fs4Ar\/","street":"22 Newton Drive","towncity":"Blackpool","postcode":"FY38BS","county":"England","country":"England","rentpw":"VCXaMj\/V6YNExbREuI08eOuINutZRxcx4vv5s2C2FR4=","nationalid":"dNDgHnJJg4rFgbb6qOEC\/dVlnJUNWLCZASo9X8GP5EE=","passport":"123456","isFavorite":""}]
```

The problem I have is that when you run the PHP code for the second time, the .json file will then look like this:

```
[{"firstName":"Ryan","lastName":"Butterworth","nationality":"rKqF01JNdAB1\/EjPW1sulcHzA+Lqp3y\/aaNtpixFphA=","phone":"6jAbOoIal2Eh73neklZgXcA2jJ3831uRiJWE74fADD8=","email":"gpLkiFg4ju4jv4QK6nftnPCqmzdENbsDt4ayI4L1rrkXvg0VJkxmP9Ac57fs4Ar\/","street":"22 Newton Drive","towncity":"Blackpool","postcode":"FY38BS","county":"England","country":"England","rentpw":"VCXaMj\/V6YNExbREuI08eOuINutZRxcx4vv5s2C2FR4=","nationalid":"dNDgHnJJg4rFgbb6qOEC\/dVlnJUNWLCZASo9X8GP5EE=","passport":"123456","isFavorite":""}]
[{"firstName":"Ryan","lastName":"Butterworth","nationality":"rKqF01JNdAB1\/EjPW1sulcHzA+Lqp3y\/aaNtpixFphA=","phone":"6jAbOoIal2Eh73neklZgXcA2jJ3831uRiJWE74fADD8=","email":"gpLkiFg4ju4jv4QK6nftnPCqmzdENbsDt4ayI4L1rrkXvg0VJkxmP9Ac57fs4Ar\/","street":"22 Newton Drive","towncity":"Blackpool","postcode":"FY38BS","county":"England","country":"England","rentpw":"VCXaMj\/V6YNExbREuI08eOuINutZRxcx4vv5s2C2FR4=","nationalid":"dNDgHnJJg4rFgbb6qOEC\/dVlnJUNWLCZASo9X8GP5EE=","passport":"123456","isFavorite":""}]
```

The Javascript loads the '.json' file as a variable, like: `var contacts = //fileoutputhere`, but as you can see the .json file now has two array lists so it runs into an error.

Instead of saving to the file like this:
`[{ ...info... }] [{ ...info... }]`

I want it to save like this:
`[{ ...info... },{ ...info... }]`

I know I'll have to tweak the PHP in some way, but not sure how I can do this. Any suggestions?

Comment: You can not append your JSON to existing file. You need to load file content, decode it in a variable, add it new data, encode and save it overwriting old file.

Comment: Sorry I'm new to working with JSON formats, could you provide a basic example of how I could achieve this? note: everything here works perfectly as expected (apart from the JS variable of course, as it is split into two arrays in the file) I was just hoping there was a way to remove the square brackets and add a comma if it detects the file exists, so it is all in one array

Comment: You'd need to read the file first to a variable, then append the new data to the array in that variable and then decode and save the file (overwriting the previous file, not appending)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With your method, you have multiple JSON strings in destination file, instead of having a unique JSON.

Start your code in this way:

```
$myFile = "userdata/". $username .".json";

if( file_exists( $myFile ) )
{
    $data = file_get_contents( $myFile );
    $return_arr = json_decode( $data, TRUE );
}
else
{
    $return_arr = array();
}
```

At this point, if the file exists, in `$return_arr` you have previously saved values. I use second parameter of `json_encode` to return an associative array for coherence with new added values, but in your case it is fully optional. If the file does not exist, `$return_arr` is an empty array.

Then proceed with your code:

```
$fetch = mysqli_query($connection, "SELECT * FROM mrb_prprty WHERE `nationalid` = '". $nationalid ."' AND `author` = '" .$username. "'");

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($fetch)) {
    (...)
}
$json_mrb = json_encode($return_arr);
```

And overwrite existing file (or create a new one):

```
$fh = fopen( $myFile, 'w' );
fwrite( $fh, $json_mrb."\n" );
```

Comment: This works perfectly, thanks for the explanation too - understand this a bit better now!

Answer (score 0):

You need to append the data to the json array, thus you have to read the file first. Here's some pseudo-code to get you started:

```
var myFile = "some-file.json";
var return_arr = array();
if(fileExists($myFile)){
    //maybe add some error handling, in case the file contents are not json?
    $return_arr = json_decode(get_file_contents($myFile));
}

while($row = getRows()){
    $row_array[x] = ...
    array_push($return_arr, $row_array);
}

$fh = $fopen($myFile, 'wa+');
fwrite(json_encode($return_arr));
```